# Getting Data from WCF request

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a very simple code to create a web service in a class.

```
Class A : ClassB
{

   void CreateService()
   {
      //Some earlier codes above
      BasicHttpBinding sBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
      sHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IEventDismiss), sBinding, baseAddr);
      sHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
      sHost.Open();
   }

   void DosomethingwithRequest()
   {
      //Get the response value from request made in class EventDismiss.
   }

}
```

IEventDismiss is the interface where I implement the Operation Contract I define in a class call EventDismiss.  Is there a way I get the value from the request itself and use it in the current classA?

The reason why I need to do this is there is a list that I maintain in class B which I need and if I create an instance of classA I'll loose this list data.  I can't modify how ClassB works because it is from a dll.

Comment: Can you show how you are invoking your service and why you would lose the the list data in class a?

Comment: Hi Jparram, I implement the typical WCF data contract service so my web service request handler is running on the class EventDismiss, if I want to refer back to classA from there I have to create a new object and this essentially reinitialize everything including that list I have.

Comment: I think i got my answer, I just put it onto a static queue on EventDismiss while having a thread to check that queue on ClassA